# Making a directory through puppet

Tags: puppet

Here my directory structure :

```
- classes
   -- test.pp
- site.pp
```

Now the content of test.pp is :

```
class test{
  file { '/puppet/test/dir' :
     ensure => directory,
  }
}
```

And my site.pp is as follows :

```
import 'classes/*.pp'

node 'nodename'{
    include test
}
```

The output of **puppet agent --no-daemonize --onetime --verbose** is showing this :

[image]

Output is saying that the puppet finished catalog thing but even then the folder is not created. What is my mistake?

Comment: Do you use Vagrant and test it there? My first thoughts would be 'nodename' is not the same as the hostname. Second, maybe you'll need to create file{ ['/puppet/test/', '/puppet/test/dir/'], ensure=>directory}. Guessing a little.

Comment: do not use import classes/*.pp. It is definitely not recommended. Use puppet module structure and include modules...

Comment: Good one @judoole, I checked the name of  the node was not the one which is to be applied the definition on.Thanks Guys, you saved my day
:D
Can you please post this as an answer so that I can accept taht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Vagrant and test it there? My first thoughts would be 'nodename' is not the same as the hostname. Second, maybe you'll need to create

```
file{ ['/puppet/test/', '/puppet/test/dir/']: 
    ensure=>directory
}
```

Guessing a little.

Copy/pasted as per request :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this a client or the puppet master?
Looks like you are missing the colon.

```
class test{
  file { '/puppet/test/dir':
    ensure => directory,
}
```

and rather than doing a `puppet agent -t` do `puppet apply site.pp`

Comment: Good one, but I checked its there and I edited the question :)

Comment: Did the `puppet apply` do anything?

Comment: I mostly do `puppet agent -t`. Try running `puppet agent -t --noop --debug`

Comment: If you don't mind you can also post up your puppet.conf maybe its looking for the site.pp file to be in the manifests directory.